# How do I announce a Bonjour service?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, bonjour, delphi-10.4.2

I am trying to implement code that announces a Bonjour service on OSX.  Out of the box, there isn't a direct way to do this.

In `Macapi.Foundation` are the following interfaces: `NSNetServiceClass` and `NSNetService`.  Then there is the wrapper class `TNSNetService`.  These are the interfaces and class that should let me announce a service.

In my class `TsdBonjourAnnouncerMac`, I have an `activate()` method which announces the service.  I followed the same code template as creating a Bonjour listener, which works fine.  However this code crashes.

The line of code `INetService := TNSNetService.Wrap(TNSNetService.OCClass.alloc);` is raising an Access Violation.  `TNSNetService.OCClass.alloc` is the offender.

I don't know how to fix this.

I found this: [Using OS X APIs directly from Delphi](http://delphiblog.twodesk.com/using_os_x_apis_directly_from_delphi).  It shows a slightly different process.  I tried using it, but was not able to call any of the methods in `NSNetService` since they aren't class methods.

How can I get this to work?

```pascal
      NSNetServiceClass = interface(NSObjectClass)
        ['{450D03AC-1380-44BA-B4C3-2D30DACACA43}']
        {class} function dataFromTXTRecordDictionary(txtDictionary: NSDictionary): NSData; cdecl;
        {class} function dictionaryFromTXTRecordData(txtData: NSData): NSDictionary; cdecl;
      end;
      NSNetService = interface(NSObject)
        ['{8FACC18E-5DFA-4526-A256-DBD7CF74B65C}']
        function TXTRecordData: NSData; cdecl;
        function addresses: NSArray; cdecl;
        function delegate: NSNetServiceDelegate; cdecl;
        function domain: NSString; cdecl;
        function getInputStream(inputStream: NSInputStream; outputStream: NSOutputStream): Boolean; cdecl;
        function hostName: NSString; cdecl;
        function name: NSString; cdecl;
        function port: NSInteger; cdecl;
        function protocolSpecificInformation: NSString; cdecl;
        procedure publish; cdecl;
        procedure publishWithOptions(options: NSNetServiceOptions); cdecl;
        procedure removeFromRunLoop(aRunLoop: NSRunLoop; forMode: NSString); cdecl;
        procedure resolve; cdecl;
        procedure resolveWithTimeout(timeout: NSTimeInterval); cdecl;
        procedure scheduleInRunLoop(aRunLoop: NSRunLoop; forMode: NSString); cdecl;
        procedure setDelegate(delegate: NSNetServiceDelegate); cdecl;
        procedure setProtocolSpecificInformation(specificInformation: NSString); cdecl;
        function setTXTRecordData(recordData: NSData): Boolean; cdecl;
        procedure startMonitoring; cdecl;
        procedure stop; cdecl;
        procedure stopMonitoring; cdecl;
      end;
      TNSNetService = class(TOCGenericImport<NSNetServiceClass, NSNetService>)  end;

 //****************************************************************************//

    TsdBonjourAnnouncerMac = class(TsdBonjourAnnouncerBase)
    private
        IDelegate:   NSNetServiceDelegate;
        INetService: NSNetService;
    protected
        function  Activate: Boolean; override;
        procedure DeActivate; override;
    public
    end;

function TsdBonjourAnnouncerMac.Activate: Boolean;
begin
    inherited;
    
    Result := True;
    INetService := TNSNetService.Wrap(TNSNetService.OCClass.alloc); // Raises access violation

    // More code to initialize

    // Set the delegate 
    
    IDelegate := TsdServiceDelegate.Create;
    
    INetService.setDelegate(NSNetServiceDelegate((IDelegate as ILocalObject).GetObjectID));
    INetService.publish;
end;
    
procedure TsdBonjourAnnouncerMac.DeActivate;
begin
end;
```

Comment: Try `TNSNetService.Wrap(TNSNetService.alloc.init)` or simply `TNSNetService.Create`. Also, which version of OSX are you using? `NSNetService` has been deprecated since macOS 10.2 in favor of the newer Network Framework.

Comment: It's not necessary to repeat tag information in either the title or body of the post. The Delphi tag suffices. Your question is also not about FreePascal, because it's about Delphi-specific code. It also helps when you add a tag for the specific version of Delphi you're using, as Firemonkey and OS support is updated frequently, so the version is relevant. There are tags for Delph-10.x-y versions, such as [tag:delphi-t0.4-Sydney].

Comment: I've [created a gist](https://gist.github.com/DelphiWorlds/ed4a938ad49072467c3f882af3ff338c) that may help you along a bit

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am using mac OS 11.5.2.

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry for that.  I have seen that before about calling it Embarcadero pascal.  I didn't have reputation points to tag it as Embarcadero.  I am using 10.4.2 with FMX framework.  Thanks for link.  I'll look at it.

Comment: @GravyJones did you try the suggestions I gave you?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I followed your suggestions but had no success

Comment: @GravyJones What happened when you tried? You will likely need to get Embarcadero Support involved in this to help you, since it is their code that is not working for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - The call to INetService.initWithDomain is not working.  NSNetService inherits from NSObject interface while NSNetServiceDelegate inherits from IObjectiveC interface.  How can I leverage the new network framework?

Comment: @GravyJones "*The call to INetService.initWithDomain is not working*" - how exactly are you calling it?

Comment: You don't need *repuation points* to add a tag to yoru question. There is already a tag here for Delphi-10.4.2-Sydney, as you can see - I added it to your question for you. You  only need reputation to *create new tags*, not to use existing ones. We don't need a tag for Embarcadero, because they're irrelevant. Delphi is the IDE being used, and 10.4.2 Sydney is the specific version.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I have tried both.  TNSNetService.Create fails silently.  INetService := TNSNetService.Wrap(TNSNetService.Alloc.Init) works. After that I create delegate like I do for the listener.  Setting the delegate to INetService fails silently.

Comment: @GravyJones then you need to contact Embarcadero Support, there is clearly something wrong with their Bridge framework.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Can you help me include the right posix units for DNS Services?  I'd like to use the posix function DNSServiceRegister to register my service. I found this link (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/dns_discovery_api/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000964)  If it is easier to use CFNetwork, then can you point me at something?

Comment: @GravyJones sorry, this is going out of my area of expertise.

Comment: @DaveNottage - I got your example to work after looking at Remy's and some objective-c code.  In objective-c code, I see bonjour announcers, initializing with alloc.initWithDomain. 'FService := TNSNetService.Wrap(TNSNetService.Alloc.initWithDomain(StrToNSStr('local.'), StrToNSStr('_' + FServiceName + '._tcp.'), StrToNSStr(''), FPort));'
  FService.setDelegate(NSNetServiceDelegate((FServiceDelegate as ILocalObject).GetObjectID));

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/DelphiWorlds/ed4a938ad49072467c3f882af3ff338c for my comment (from knut) to see how I got it to work